# Get text between html tags using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to retrieve text from HTML tags and apply indexing to the text.

**Input**

```
<div>this <span>is</span> my<p>first</p>program</div>
```

**Output**

```
<div> this 1
<span> is  2
<div> my  3
<p>   first 4
<div> program 5
```

Comment: Post your code please!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a CSS Selector query:

```
doc.select("div").first().text();
doc.select("span").first().text();
doc.select("div > span + p ").first().text();
```